# Best practice database schema for property booking calendar

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I am working on a multiple properties booking system and making me headache about the best practice schema design. Assume the site hosts for example 5000 properties where each of it is maintained by one user. Each property has a booking calendar. My current implementation is a two-table-system with one table for the available dates and the other for the unavailable dates, with a granularity of 1 day each.

> property_dates_available (property_id, date);
>
> property_dates_booked (property_id, date);

However, i feel unsure if this is a good solution. In another question i read about a single table solution with both states represented. But i wonder if it is a good idea to mix them up. Also, should the booking calendar be mapped for a full year with all its 365 days per year into the database table or was it better to map only the days a property is available for booking? I think of the dramatically increasing number of rows every year. Also i think of searching the database lately for available properties and am not sure if looking through 5000 * 365 rows might be a bad idea compared to i.e. only 5000 * av. 100 rows.

What would you generally recommend? Is this aspect ignorable? How to best practice implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a separate table for available dates. If you have a table for booked dates (property_id, date), then you can easily query this table to find out which properties are available for a given date

```
select properties.property_name
from properties where not exists
(select 1 from property_dates_booked
 where properties.property_id = property_dates_booked
 and property_dates_booked.date = :date)
```

:date being a parameter to the query

Only enter actual bookings into the property_dates_booked table (it would be easier to rename the table 'bookings'). If a property is not available for certain dates because of maintenance, then enter a booking for those dates where the customer is 'special' (maybe the 'customer' has a negative id).

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I have to do some playaround with it and will come back to either continue this topic or accept your answer.

Comment: I did some playarounds and found the schema (id, property_id, date, state) to be a good start. This would result in each date available being one row in the table. A booking for a specific date would change the state variable. But i see new problem with this solution. What if at least two users send a booking request for the exact same 7 days to be stored into the database? How to ensure that there won't happen a mixery of booking assignments between these users?

Comment: @user1014412: your program would first check whether the property is available for the dates given (that's the query which I wrote in my answer). The property will be available for the first user, but not available for the second user.

Comment: Since this check is applied for both users right before they store their booking requests into the db, in my opinion this does not bind the whole bunch to one specific user. I understand your example as a pre-check for the state var not as some kind of lock. This leads me to take some race condition into account and force a table write lock for the winner who can then write its changes into the db, right?

Comment: I still stuck with this problem. I encountered the conflict where 2 events happen the same day - checkin and checkout on the same property but by different users. If i'd stick with the current scheme (1 table with every date as separate row) i cannot implement this, since i cannot mark 1 date both, available and available or available and booked or booked and booked. Since a week going from e.g. Sat. to Sat i may regularly encounter this kind of collision. I cannot imagine how this could be reliable implemented within 1 table. Do you know a good way?

Comment: @user1014412: I'm trying to imagine what happened. Someone booked property A on Thursday 14 March and checks out on 15 March. So the property should be seen by a second user as occupied on 14 and free on 15. Checkouts are irrelevant - they only serve to show when the property is freed. If people can hire rooms by the hour (so to speak), then you need a different granularity. Your week above should be represented as Sat-Fri (7 nights), not Sat-Sat (8 nights).

Comment: The last sentence is exactly the point. It is a requirement, that every week counts from e.g. Sat-Sat, where first Sat is checkin at from 12 a.m. and the last Sat is checkout up to 12 a.m. Both "half days" are count as 1 day thus making all together a booking of 7 days. I have no choice. I must use this concept Fr-Fr, Sat-Sat and so on, which is, why i'm getting crazy here. Wasting time cuz of this concept limiting everything that much.

Comment: That requirement is wrong; even your Sat-Sat does not have overlap. Count the nights, not the days.

Comment: I'm afraid, i don't see, what you see. If i store 14 rows e.g. 2013-04-01 - 2013-04-15 marked as free and user A immediately books 2013-04-01 - 2013-04-08 and user B requests 2013-04-08 - 2013-04-15 for booking, i am unable to mark 2013-04-08, which is changeover day, both, booked and requested. What do i oversee? Would you mind constructing an example using dates? I feel somewhat blind.

Comment: First of all, 14 rows would be 2013-04-01 until 2013-04-14. You're always adding on an extra day which is the problem. If user A books a week from 2013-04-01, then her days are 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06 and 07. *** O8 *** is free for user B. True, user A checks out on 04-08, but THE EVENING OF 04-08 IS FREE - for user B, who then books 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14. Again, user B checks out on 04-15, but the evening of 04-15 is free for someone else.

Comment: ok, now i see your point. In fact i already had this thought too, but dropped it 'gain for any reason. Have to re-evaluate this.